# How do unmarshalling to different objects depending on the XML received?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb

I have a web service which receives XML files and does unmarshalling to convert the XML file to an object. The problem is that my web service can receive different XML structures and has to do the correct unmarshalling.

So I receibe this kind of XML files:

```
<root>
    <user>
        <id>1234</id>
    </user>
    <XMLelements>
        ...
    </XMLelements>
</root>
```

Notice that `XMLelements` is an example tag name, every XML file could have differents names.

So, I think, my web service workflow should be something like:

1. It receives XML file.
2. It checks user id.

   - If user id == 1234

     - UserA userA = unmarshalling(XMLFile)
   - Else if user id == 5678

     - UserB userB = unmarshalling(XMLFile)
   - Else

     - UserC userC = unmarshalling(XMLFile)

So I receive different XML structures and for each one I have to do a different unmarshalling to get objects of different classes.

How can I perform this approach? I'm using Spring for marshalling (Metro).

**Edit:** This question didn't receive any answer, maybe I'm not clear. I'll try to explain it better:

I have a web service which is listening a url where receives XML files. Actually, in the same url path my web service receives two different XML schemas. How can I know how to do unmarshalling correctly? I mean, unmarshalling should return correct object when different XML schemas are passed.

Comment: Which part of the XML structure is common to both XML schemas is there an envelope portion?)?  What part of the message signals which schema the message corresponds to (is there a body portion?)?  Are you looking for something like this:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html

Comment: I'm looking for something like your blog post, but the two different XML schemas have the same root element name, and also some element name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to support this use case.

---

**OPTION #1 - DOM Approach**

You could always use a DOM parser to convert the XML to a `Document` perform an XPath against it to get the value of the `id` element and then unmarshal the document based on the result

---

**OPTION #2 - SAX Approach**

***LookAheadUnmarshallerHandler***

You could leverage a SAX parser and JAXB's `UnmarshallerHandler` mechanism and do the following:

- Create a `ContentHandler` that queues up SAX events until the necessary information is discovered.
- Create/retrieve a `JAXBContext` based on the value of the `id` element.
- Create an `UnmarshallerHandler` from the `JAXBContext`.
- Call the queued events on the `UnmarshallerHandler`.
- Set the `UnmarshallerHandler` on the `XMLReader` as the `ContentHandler`.
- Retrieve the unmarshalled object from the `UnmarshallerHandler`.

```java
package forum13397834;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class LookAheadUnmarshallerHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private XMLReader xmlReader;
    private List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
    private UnmarshallerHandler unmarshallerHandler;

    public LookAheadUnmarshallerHandler(XMLReader xmlReader) {
        this.xmlReader = xmlReader;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        events.add(new StartElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes));
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        if("id".equals(localName) || "id".equals(qName)) {
            Characters characters = (Characters) events.get(events.size() - 1);
            String value = characters.getString();
            JAXBContext jc;
            try {
                if("1234".equals(value)) {
                    jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root1.class);
                } else if("5678".equals(value)) {
                    jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root2.class);
                } else {
                    jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root3.class);
                }
                unmarshallerHandler = jc.createUnmarshaller().getUnmarshallerHandler();
            } catch(JAXBException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            unmarshallerHandler.startDocument();
            for(Event event : events) {
                event.event(unmarshallerHandler);
            }
            unmarshallerHandler.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
            xmlReader.setContentHandler(unmarshallerHandler);
        } else {
            events.add(new EndElement(uri, localName, qName));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        events.add(new Characters(ch, start, length));
    }

    public Object getResult() throws JAXBException {
        return unmarshallerHandler.getResult();
    }

    private static abstract class Event {

        public abstract void event(ContentHandler contentHandler) throws SAXException; 

    }

    private static class StartElement extends Event {

        private String uri;
        private String localName;
        private String qName;
        private Attributes attributes;

        public StartElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) {
            this.uri = uri;
            this.localName = localName;
            this.qName = qName;
            this.attributes = attributes;
        }

        @Override
        public void event(ContentHandler contentHandler) throws SAXException {
            contentHandler.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
        }

    }

    private static class Characters extends Event {

        private char[] ch;
        private int start;
        private int length;

        public Characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
            this.ch = ch;
            this.start = start;
            this.length = length;
        }

        @Override
        public void event(ContentHandler contentHandler) throws SAXException {
            contentHandler.characters(ch, start, length);
        }

        public String getString() {
            return new String(ch, start, length);
        }

    }

    private static class EndElement extends Event {

        private String uri;
        private String localName;
        private String qName;

        public EndElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) {
            this.uri = uri;
            this.localName = localName;
            this.qName = qName;
        }

        @Override
        public void event(ContentHandler contentHandler) throws SAXException {
            contentHandler.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
        }

    }

}
```

**JAVA MODEL**

The following object model is based on the classes you mention in your question.

***UserA***

```java
package forum13397834;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="root")
public class UserA {

}
```

***UserB***

```java
package forum13397834;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="root")
public class UserB {

}
```

***UserC***

```java
package forum13397834;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="root")
public class UserC {

}
```

**INPUT (input.xml)**

We will use the XML document from your question as the input for this example.

```
<root>
    <user>
        <id>1234</id>
    </user>
    <XMLelements>
        ...
    </XMLelements>
</root>
```

**DEMO CODE**

```java
package forum13397834;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XMLReader xmlReader = spf.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();

        LookAheadUnmarshallerHandler handler = new LookAheadUnmarshallerHandler(xmlReader);
        xmlReader.setContentHandler(handler);
        xmlReader.parse(new InputSource("src/forum13397834/input.xml"));
        Object object = handler.getResult();
        System.out.println(object.getClass());
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
class forum13397834.UserA
```

Comment: Thank you Blaise, It seems what I'm looking for. I have to integrate it with Spring framework and I'll see if It works correctly