# Multiple marshallers/unmarshallers with Spring OXM

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, marshalling, spring-oxm

I have a legacy web service project that receives two different XML schemas, but with the same attribute name (including the root element). I'm using Spring, OXM and JAXB2 for marshalling/unmarshalling.

I've solved a previous issue with [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397834/how-do-unmarshalling-to-different-objects-depending-on-the-xml-received), so I use SAX parser to determine which unmarshaller to use. When a XML is parsed, I check a value and then I can use an unmarshaller or other unmarshaller.

My problem comes when I try to define marshallers/unmarhsallers with Spring OXM. If I set the classpath with two packages, it fails beacause unmarshaller finds two classes with the same XMLRootElement. If I set a list of class-to-be-bound it fails too beacause unmarshaller always unmarshall to the last item in the class list (same XMLRootElement, unmarshaller doesn't know which class to unmarshall).

But It works correctly If I use JaxbContext:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass1.class);
myClass1Object = (MyClass1) jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

And

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass2.class);
myClass2Object = (MyClass2) jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

How can I transform this to a more Spring (OXM) approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I tried to declare the JAXBContext instance in the application context file, but finally I went for changing the namespace of one XML schema. Now I'm using Spring OXM to marshall/unmarshall my two XML schemas without any problem.